# Dynamic Page Header/Footer width in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

How is it possible to control the width of the page header and page footer (dynamically) based on the detail record in ssrs.

I am using a **matrix** in my detail section. Here, more month names can be added based on data. The width of header should be of same length of matrix width from detail section.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be the page header? If you make it the table header it will size with the matrix and you can have table headers repeat across pages which should achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

Now this answer isnt the cleanest but you could create 2 different size headers that are on top of each other. Then in the Header properties; use an expression in the "Hidden" property like so:

**First Header**

```
=iif(Parameters!YourParameter.Value < 3,TRUE,FALSE)
```

**Second Header**

```
=iif(Parameters!YourParameter.Value >= 3,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Now the 1st Header will be hidden when the value is less than 3 and the 2nd header will be hidden when the value is greater than or equal to 3.